# Wordpress setting custom Frontpage

Tags: wordpress

how can I make a link that is coming from a plugin the frontpage

**ex:** /wp-content/plugins/documente/documentations/medias_v4/index.html

or

**ex:** /?p=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your active theme, make a file called `front-page.php` or edit an existing one. In it, add a line in the beginning: `<?php include '/wp-content/plugins/documente/documentations/medias_v4/index.html'; exit; ?>`

Comment: i'm receiving a blank page

Comment: You could also try `'/../../plugins/documente/documentations/medias_v4/index.html'`. Is your wordpress install directory in a subdirectory on your domain?

Comment: it's not in a subdomain... I tried home.php too, also tried interesting random text and that did not show either.

Comment: Thats odd. It works on my install. I have another page set as static home page in settings->reading. Any error messages? Perhaps in your server's log files?

Comment: no error nothing... even tried changing to the default them

Comment: Double check two things: 1) the file you added the line to is actually being loaded. For that, add something random at the beginning of the file, like 'TEST'. 2) That the file path you're using is correct. A typo can ruin your day. Also, you have error displaying off, otherwise you'd see SOMETHING. Would it be possible to turn it on?

Comment: i tried "This is a test" with <?php phpinfo(); ?> and it loaded so it's processing PHP it just doesn't like the included hmm